# If node.js is single threaded then why does server.listen() return?

Tags: node.js

I am familiar with event based systems in c++ as well as java. I was trying to learn node.js and ran into interesting behavior and I was hoping someone can explain what is going on under the hood.

I have a program that looks like

```
var http = require("http");


function main(){
    // Console will print the message
    console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/');
    var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {

        // Send the HTTP header
        // HTTP Status: 200 : OK
        // Content Type: text/plain
        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

        // Send the response body as "Hello World"
        response.end('Hello World\n');
    });

    server.listen(8080); //Why is this not blocking
    console.log('Main completed');

    //main loop here prevents other stuff from working
}

main();
```

In languages like java or c I would expect two things. Either server.listen provides an event loop which would cause server.listen to never return. Or server.listen spawns a new thread and runs the event loop in the new thread returning right away. Then it would call console.log and then return and close the program.

To test this I also added a busy loop below the console.log that looks like.

```
var http = require("http");


function main(){
    // Console will print the message
    console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/');
    var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {

        // Send the HTTP header
        // HTTP Status: 200 : OK
        // Content Type: text/plain
        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

        // Send the response body as "Hello World"
        response.end('Hello World\n');
    });

    server.listen(8080); //Why is this not blocking
    console.log('Main completed');

    while(true){
        console.log('hi');
    }
}

main();
```

Server.listen returns right away and then gets stuck in the busy loop as expected. My browser can not connect to the server, which is expected.

If I remove the busy loop and go back to the original code once console.log('Main completed'); is executed instead of the program exiting, the main thread jumps back into the event loop.

How does this work. Why does the main thread jump back into the server code after the main thread returns?

Edit:
I think re resolved that the event queue does not exist within the main function but where is it? What owns it? and when does the main function get run in reference to it?

Comment: Useful: http://blog.mixu.net/2011/02/01/understanding-the-node-js-event-loop/

Comment: I understand that part of the event loop. My question concerns the fact that the main thread exits and looks like it jumps back up to another point.

Comment: because server.listen this is async function. It would be good for you to read about LivUV and EventEmmiter

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Think of `http.createServer(handler)` and `server.listen(port)` as being kinda similar to `someElement.addEventListener('click', handler)` in the browser.

When you run `someElement.addEventListener('click', handler)`, it binds an event listener that will send `handler` to the callback queue when the click event is triggered on `someElement`.

`http.createServer(handler)` combined with `server.listen(port)` work in a very similar way. `http.createServer(handler)` returns an `eventEmitter`, and `server.listen(port)` tells node.js that when an http request is received on the given port, this event should be triggered. Thus, when a request comes in, the event is triggered, and `handler` is pushed to the callback queue.

At this point, it's just a simple matter of how the event loop callstack and callback queue interact. The **callstack** is the currently executing stack of functions, the **callback queue** is a collection of callbacks waiting to be executed, and the **event loop** is what pulls callbacks off of the **callback queue** and sends them to the **callstack**.

So, in a sense, the event loop is what keeps everything going, however, if you block the callstack from emptying by having a synchronous infinite loop in one of your callbacks, the event loop never runs again and callbacks never get executed resulting in a broken/unresponsive application.

Comment: If you still don't quite understand the event loop/callback queue/callstack, watch this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

Comment: Your answer Helped a lot. Im not asking how the event loop works. It is more where it is? I was under the impression that it was within listen. But I understand now that it is not but it still has to be somewhere. For example in java. If your going to set up an event queue. You first create an executor that acts as the event queue and then push events/runnables onto it. The same principle has to apply to node. That event queue has to exist somewhere. I am just trying to figure out where it is.

Comment: The way I understand it (i may be wrong... do further research) is that node.js implements both the callback queue and the event loop, not the callstack. you have no control of it, all you can do is influence it by clearing the callstack consistently, or blocking it.

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental concept to understand here is the event loop and the [cooperative (non-preemptive) multitasking model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-preemptive_multitasking).

That `server.listen` call registers a callback with the event loop underneath, and that callback shares the main execution thread with every other registered callback.

When you throw that busy loop in, the `server.listen` callback never gets execution time (and neither does the event engine, for that matter), because the system is *non-preemptive*.  That is, no callback can interrupt any other - callbacks must relinquish control back to the event loop by terminating, whereupon the event loop will call other registered callbacks based on events it has queued.

Comment: How does the end of the main function know to jump back into the event loop though?

Comment: That main function is at a higher level than the event loop, which is part of the engine itself.  When the main function launches, the event loop is sitting still.  When the main function stops, the event loop starts.  It's the nature of node: the state "*event loop listening for events, no callbacks running*" is essentially node's ground state.

Comment: I think I get it. The main function in itself is a processed event? So when the main function is done it returns back to the event loop ruining in the engine?

Comment: no, it's a function. :) your callstack looks kinda like this: `global -> main` until `main` returns, `global` can't return. the callstack won't be empty until `global` returns, and the event loop only.. loops when the callstack is empty. `main` in your code won't return until the while loop finishes... which is never, so the event loop will never run.

Comment: Another good article I found on [Concurrency model and Event Loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop) Site

Comment: `main` isn't an event callback, but it isn't the root execution context either. (@KevinB knows what's up.)  The important thing is that when `main` returns, the execution loop is ready and spinning.

Comment: is the event loop then considered the root execution context? So then once main returns control is given to the event loop?

Comment: i don't think i would consider it the root execution context, as there is something outside of both the event loop and the javascript runtime that handles things that are outside of javascript, such as filesystem access and sockets, which inserts callbacks into the callback queue when complete (which then gets processed by the eventloop) but we're getting in to an area that i'm not too familiar with, i'm more knowledgeable of the javascript side of this which includes the callstack, the eventloop, and the callback queue.

Comment: You can think of `server.listen()` as being similar to `div.addEventListener('click', handler)` in the browser. It binds an event, and then continues. It doesn't block the thread. From a javascript perspective, the two are near identical. They simply call an api that was made available by the environment the javascript is executing in. the end result is an event is bound, and any time that event is triggered, the callback gets sent to the callback queue, which in turn gets processed by the event loop and eventually executed by the `main` context, thus adding the callback to the callstack.

Comment: (cont.) but, as explained before, since your while loop prevents `main()` from returning, and thus prevents the callstack from clearing, the callbacks being sent to the callback queue never get executed because the event loop never runs.

Answer (score 0):

Basically `http.createServer` returns a pointer to an `EventEmitter`. You can attach listeners etc. to the object that will be executed when an event is emitted. These are processed inside of the event loop which is run asynchronously and do not block the main thread. Checkout the [HTTP](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_server) documentation for more information about `HTTP` and `EventEmitters`.

Comment: If the call is asynchronous then why does the busy loop prevent the events from getting processed?

Comment: because the busy loop prevents all callbacks from being processed as well; the event loop can't run until the callstack is clear.